# T. Hanaoka's "Note on c-realcompact spaces and mappings"

Tags: gn.general-topology, paper-request, realcompact-spaces

I need T. Hanaoka's article *Note on c-realcompact spaces and mappings*, Memoirs of the Osaka Kyoiku Univ., Ser. Ill, 26 (1977), 55-58.

Can anyone find it for me?

http://ir.lib.osaka-kyoiku.ac.jp/dspace/handle/123456789/10422